# Algebra manipulation: given $x+y = xy = 3$, evaluate $x^3 + y^3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, problem-solving, cubics

Tasked with a brainteaser, I am stuck on this one. The question follows:

> Given $x+y = xy = 3$, evaluate $x^3 + y^3$

Can you solve this? If so, please provide the steps you took.

[image: Attempt so far]

Comment: Show what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks. Will update question now

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Use this for future reference to format your questions: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/321264.

Comment: Regarding the image, $3^3$ is $27$, not $81$. But since you're making that same mistake twice, just subtract the fake $3^3$ from both sides of your final equation, and what is left on both sides is $0=x^3+y^3$. In other words, you're "stuck" half a second before the solution!

Comment: (Note, by the way, that $xy=x+y=3$ requires $x$ and $y$ to be complex).

Answer (score 4):

HINT: Expand $(x+y)^3$ and group the terms properly, and you’ll find that you can write it as a function of $x+y$ and $xy$. If you’re still stuck after giving that some thought, check the spoiler-protected block below.

> $(x+y)^3=x^3+y^3+3xy(x+y)$

Comment: Thanks. This solved my question

Comment: @H.F.D: You’re welcome.

Comment: Another way of seeing it is $x^3+y^3$ $=(x+y)\left(x^2-xy+y^2\right)$ $=(x+y)\left((x+y)^2-3xy\right)$.